# mod rewrite with dots

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

i want to change a url like : `localhost/site/home.php?p=index` to `localhost/site/index`

i use this code in my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ home.php?p=$1 [L,NS]
```

but when i write like `localhost/site/home.php?p=profile.user` i get the 404 error, and go to this link

> localhost/profile.user

so how can i fix it
thanks

Comment: What other rewrite rules do you have? You have to post details.

Comment: `RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$           home.php?p=$1 [L,NS] `

Comment: I do not get any errors here. Are you sure you are not missing any other details? And update any details by editing the question itself.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody caught the wrong-way rewrite! Unanswered for weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at your rewrites first:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ home.php?p=$1 [L,NS]
```

This is *relative* rewrite: the replacement text `home.php...` does not begin with a slash. Relative rewrites in a per-directory context (`<Directory>` or `.htaccess`) require a `RewriteBase` directive to be configured, otherwise they do the wrong thing.

Secondly, your rule is backwards, If you want to rewrite the `home.php` URL to  the `site/index` one, you have to put the `home.php` match on the left side, and the `site/index` on the right:

```
RewriteRule ^home.php?p=(.*) /site/$1
```

Notice that I have an absolute rewrite. This means that mod_rewrite will create a URL out of the rewrite by sticking `http://example.com` on it. A new request is internally generated now for `http://example.com/site/<whatever>`.  We can get away without using `RewriteBase` since we have no relative rewrites.

As for your last question, it is not clear why when you access `localhost/site/home.php?p=profile.user` you're being taken to `localhost/profile.user`. I'm suspecting that it's your `home.php` script doing that, perhaps. You're trying to use `mod_rewrite` to hijack that particular kind of PHP request and send it elsewhere, right?

Comment: I think he didn't express himself properly. A lot of people do this actually: instead of saying "i want to rewrite `localhost/site` to `home.php?blabla` they say the opposite, which is both a mistake and wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What you meant is probably: you want to rewrite this way:

```
http://mysite.com/index => http://mysite.com/home.php?p=index
```

So this should work

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^/?$ /home.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

---

Now if you want **the opposite**:

```
http://mysite.com/home.php?p=index => http://mysite.com/index
```

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule /home\.php$ / [QSA,L]
```